# Using React and .jsx with Electron

Tags: electron, reactjs

Trying to get an Electron project going using React and its .jsx files. I've gone through various tutorials, github issues, SO answers, and the like, but I have not found a clear guide to setting up an Electron project for use with React and it's `.jsx` files.

What steps, dependencies, and configurations are needed to get this working?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: Yes, I did come across that project, but they are using .js files for their components instead of .jsx.

Comment: .jsx and .js files do not matter. You can use them interchangeably. The difference is you need to tell webpack to look for jsx extensions in addition to js extensions and you have to add `.jsx` when you import files. If you just use js extensions, you can just say `import Component from '../path/to/component` and leave off the file extension. And you can still have jsx in js files

Comment: Why do you have to add the `.jsx` extension in the import statement? I've never had to do that before. Another reason to use .jsx is for syntax highlighting.

Comment: depends how your webpack is set up. what issue are you having exactly

Comment: Not having an exact issue, as much as looking for a sort of guide. I understand the basics of webpack and babel an other common parts of the nodejs ecosystem but setting them up to play nicely without a guide is a bit difficult.

Comment: It's definitely extremely difficult to get it started without a guide while trying to figure it all out. My best suggestion is to start with a sample project, like the one I provided and dissect that and make changes accordingly. It will help you understand how everything is set up and works together.

Answer (score 9):

We found that there are 2 processes that need to be *bootstrapped*.

First, install babel-register et al and set up .babelrc to handle react, es6, etc. I won't go into those details here...

Let's assume your main script is called main.js and your render script (containing jsx,es6,react, etc) is called render.js

main.boot.js

```
// install babel hooks in the main process
require('babel-register');
require('./main.js');
```

For the render process, you add the babel-register script to the html file *before* your render script.

```
<script>
        // install babel hooks in the renderer process
        require('babel-register');
</script>
<script src='render.js'></script>
```

Then simply call the bootstrap script instead of the main one from your project. For example, change Package.json to something like

```
"main": "./main.boot.js"
```

And make sure you get your source paths correct :)

Comment: Really cool to see this example requires only babel-register (giving you React JSX and ES6) and not webpack :D

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `test: /\.tsx?$/,` to `test: /\.jsx?$/`and entry to `index.jsx` in configs/, it started working for me.

**index.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a package for that purpose, maybe helps you

You just need to put this in your html:

```
<script>
require("electron-jsx")(__dirname, {
    reactDir: "./react-sources",
})
</script>
<script react-src="./react-sources/index.jsx">
```

And set in BrowserView:

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-jsx

https://github.com/mdjfs/electron-jsx